# I need help getting a new average in my loop

Tags: c++

So I'm creating an array loop using functions to ask the user to input grades, and then get the average. I want to have it set so that at the end of getting your first average you can enter another set of grades and get a new average. The problem is that a new average is not being made and it's just reoutputting the average of the first run through.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int setLength();
void getGrade(int[], int);
double getAverage(int[], int);

int main()
{
    const int alength = setLength();
    int gradearray[alength];
    string ans;

    for (int e = 0; e < alength; e++)
    {
        gradearray[e] = 0;
    };

    getGrade(gradearray, alength);
    double avg = getAverage(gradearray, alength);   
    cout << "The average grade is " << avg << "%\n"
         << "Would you like to calculate the average of another set of grades? \n";
    cin  >> ans;

    if (ans == "yes" || ans == "Yes" || ans == "y" || ans == "Y" || ans == "1")
        while (ans == "yes" || ans == "Yes" || ans == "y" || ans == "Y" || ans == "1")
        {
                const int alength = setLength();
                getGrade(gradearray, alength);
                getAverage(gradearray, alength);

                cout << "The average grade is " << avg << "%\n"
                << "Would you like to calculate the average of another set of grades? \n";
                cin  >> ans;
        }

    return 0;
 }
```

I expect a new output to come out of the new loop. I am getting a repeat of the first average.

Comment: `const int alength = setLength();
    int gradearray[alength];` is not valid C++ (VLA extension), use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Assignments like this are just mean.

Answer (score 0):

The second time you call `getAverage` you are not assigning the returned value to anything. It is simply discarded and `avg` retains its previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how you get the average first time around

```
 double avg = getAverage(gradearray, alength);
```

now look at how you get the average second time around

```
 getAverage(gradearray, alength);
```

See the difference?

BTW the if statement here is redundent

```
if (ans == "yes" || ans == "Yes" || ans == "y" || ans == "Y" || ans == "1")
    while (ans == "yes" || ans == "Yes" || ans == "y" || ans == "Y" || ans == "1")
```

Just use a while loop.